# boxplot at a certain x, y location in matplotlib, seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, visualization, seaborn

I have some data which is organized as follows:

```
x     y     score
1     1     0.951
1     1     0.956
1     1     0.976
1     1     0.875
1.5   1.5   0.94
1.5   1.5   0.76
1.5   1.5   0.88
...
10    10    0.51
10    10    0.66
```

So what I want to do is aggregate the data by `(x, y)` values and then show a box plot for the `score` at those `(x, y)` values.

I realize that I will need 2 y-axes and I think `matplotlib` allows one to do that. I see an example here: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/two_scales.html

However, I am not sure if it is even possible to arrange this so that the scales will correspond to the means of these datasets.

So, I am guessing my question is whether this can be done or if there is a recommendation on how to visualise this sort of data?

Comment: I don't follow why a second scale is needed and for what purpose.

Comment: Because the usual x and y axes will be taken up by the `(x, y)` values and the score value would require a third axes?

Comment: So the absolute value of the `score` is irrelevant?